# Import library to directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, import, directive, jshint

when I run grunt jshint it gives me an error:

```
'Modernizr' is not defined.
'IScroll' is not defined.
```

the error is arguing about the library used in directive is not defined. I tried a dummy way:

```
.directive('iScroll', function(IScroll, Modernizr) {…});
```

but again error. The question is how can I ignore this error or how can I import these libraries in my directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
/* global Modernizr */
/* global IScroll */
```

at the very top of your directive file

**EDIT:** when including the library as a global usually is bad practice and bit hard for unit testing. the better solution is using

```
$window.IScroll, $window.Modernizr
```

whenever call these IScroll or Modernizr